# Multi pendant light fixture

Tags: electrical

I have an eight pendant light fixture that has a single long canopy. Each pendant has its own set of three wires. How can i wire these all to the ceiling wires? Do i use some dype of daisy chain or a connector box? I cant imagine witei g eight different wires to a single set coming from the ceiling … thanks

Comment: Did the light not come with installation instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Wago makes an eight slot connector, but you'd still need another (second) set of 3 connectors to add a jumper between them and add the incoming wires.

Six, 6-slot would work, again with jumpers.

But if it's un-tinned stranded wire, I'd just use twist nuts... with solid jumpers into wagos. Depending on the nut, you're going to need a bunch of them because there's a given maximum number of wires, per size, that can go into one.

Comment: I started using the wago lever locks a few years back they work well on both solid and stranded. I think the lever locks are a better choice for DIY as there is no skill compared to a wire nut.